# how can i add one NSMutablearray to another empty NSmutablearray?

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutablearray, uisearchbar, nsmutabledictionary

I am using NSMutableDictionary for storing data into key value pair and append these dictionary to NSMutableArray.I want to assign my filtered NSMUtablearray to another empty NSMUtablearray, but can not get result and app is crash dunring searching some text..

here is my code:

```
extension ViewController: UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate
{
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String)
{
    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchText)
    let result = ArrData.filtered(using: searchPredicate)
    searchCoin.add(result)
    searchActive = true
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
}
```

crash is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxTnC.png)

Comment: Add your code and error as text.It will help for answer to the question.

Comment: Why do you need `NSMutableDictionary` in this case?

Comment: Also as @Dilan mentioned, you have to include code as **Plain text**, so that search engines can find.

Comment: are you sure you have dictionaries on each index of the array ?

Comment: The exception message tells you that the array contains an empty array, not a mutable dictionary. You should basically never use `NS` types in swift. Use properly typed Swift collections and you will catch errors like this at compile time.

Comment: @jawadAli yes i m sure

Comment: @LalKrishna because i have to add my api data into dictionary and add that dictionary to NSMutableArray

Answer (score 0):

Just change the code from

```
 let dict = self.filteredArray.object(at: IndexPath.row) as! NSMutableDictionary
```

to

```
 let dictOptional = self.filteredArray.object(at: IndexPath.row) as? NSMutableDictionary
 guard let dict = dictOptional else {
      print("Error at: \(IndexPath.row) - can't convert to dictionary")
 }
```

If You want more - write the types of ArrData, filteredArray - how You create and use it